# How to Search within json document in apache solr lucene

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

below is the json sample i have imported to solr where id is unique and json_doc field contains whole json.

{ "id" : "cust_123",
  "json_doc" : "{ "\first_name\":\"xyz\",
                  \"last_name\":\"ABC\",
                  \"address\":\"#s3,Apple store,New York,USA}\" 
                }"
}

Now i want to search within the json document like Apple store as query or New york as query or USA .... and i should get the document ...

**Want help to define schema.xml for this kind of request.**

if you use space tokenizer then it will tokenize on space ... so if i will search for "apple store" then it will not match ....

Please help me

Comment: Is there some reason why you indexed the whole JSON in a single field? Normally & Naturally & Intuitively: you're supposed to split the JSON to separate fields.

Comment: because if my json documents changes .. i dont want to add the fields in the schema .. and if i have different json documents like customer info document, address info document or order info document  or wish list info document ..... and tomorrow i have to add the page view history document for user then ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to index JSON documents: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON

And here's how to get search results in a JSON doc: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJSON

If you, on the other hand, have some weird requirement to store the whole document in a single field please tell...

Comment: thanks for respond ...

yes .. i want to store whole json document in the filed ... 

and i am very much confused about the schema ...

Comment: plz help on the following issue ... confused only for right schema

Comment: You wont be able to do fast searches with "whole JSON in a single field" setup. The whole point of schema is that you "tell" Solr which fields are going to be searched, so it can build fast access data structure with those fields' values. So, I don't see a reason against adding those fields in schema. Especially if you can use dynamic fields: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields

Comment: thanks for your reply. but here i have 2 questions


1.Is it possible to get custom tokenizer which will create tokens based on "( double quote ) or any other delimiter ? i know i can apply filter with payload delimiter or something ... Any suggestion/idea ????

Comment: 2.i have to dump all the fields i want's to use for searching.so it's like sql table defining a column and then get result.
but if in sql table you are having a blob field contains the text and you wants to search anything then you dont have to define so many things ... same objective i want to achieve .. you just dump your document and search within that document ... 


Any input for this kind of request ?

Comment: 1. Yes it's possible, but it'll require more time than to define dynamic fields.

Comment: my main objective is to do search within document .. it may be json, may be text, may be html .... doesn't matter actually ....

Help/suggestion ...

Comment: 2. You basically always have to balance between (boilerplate & over-configuration) and (efficiency & functionality). The more detailed schema definition will provide more input to Solr, so it'll handle your data better and provide users with better overall experience. IMHO: You cannot even begin to compare full-text search inside sql blob and Solr.

Comment: The point is that you are going to search within document, only data wont be in a single field. So what about dynamic fields? Why do you think that wont work for you?

Comment: any help document to meet objective 1 ?

Comment: because i don't have full list of dynamic fields exists in system, i have to use  <dynamicField name="*"  type="text_general"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>  and this will down the performance.. right ??? 

the request json is not in my control. if tomorrow they add some more fields or remove fields .. then i have to change solr schema to handle that .... which is quite headache or it's like apply patches each time .. whenever your request json changes .. right ..

My main objective is to avoid maintaining the schema document each time the json changes ... Any solution ?

Comment: Dynamic fields wont degrade indexing performance. If you want to search the values you'll need to have those dynamic fields. Why would you need to change schema if you use "*"?

Comment: correct .. if i use * then no worry for schema rewrite ... but what about performance ?

Comment: Objective1: If you want to build your own way of handling index updates you would need to create custom UpdateRequestProcessor. Take a look how Selvam did the similar thing in this post: http://knackforge.com/blog/selvam/integrating-solr-and-mahout-classifier

Comment: thanks !! ... 

i want to search within address and text is new york, i have enabled debug log and below is debug log ....


rawquerystring: "shipment_recepient_name6:New york",
querystring: "shipment_recepient_name6:New york",
parsedquery: "+shipment_recepient_name6:New +shipment_recepient_name1:york ",
parsedquery_toString: "+shipment_recepient_name6:New +shipment_recepient_name1:york ",

My doubt is i am searching on field6 and why its doing search on field1(my default search field) .can you suggest a schema where i can search the address and based on the highest matching score returns res

Comment: So now your JSON is no longer all-in-one-field, right, you have stored it in multiple fields?

Comment: Can you please ask a new question for this new problem.

Comment: posted new question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277987/wants-field-type-schema-xml-for-address-search-from-customer-order-details

Comment: If my comments helped, can you please close this question?